# Make Splash Screen optional in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, splash-screen, vb.net-2010

I may not be explaining myself the best with the question, I'm usually bad at that. But I'll try my best.

This to me seems like something that would be fairly simple, I'm builing a program in Visual Basic and it has a Splash Screen. While I like the clean splash screen, some users might not and I want to give them a simple way to disable it using a defined setting in the program.

This setting when false would disable the splash screen, when true the splash screen would show up (default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is either on the splash screen itself, on the bottom left or right, put a checkbox that says "Don't show again" and if they check it, save the setting and next time you load the application check that and decide accordingly. Or alternatively, you can put it under the settings/options of the application too. Some do it in both areas to ensure that if the user ever wants it back, they can get it without manually editing the setting for it. Any further suggestions or examples, let me know and I can whip something up for you but this should be pretty self explanatory.